# javascript игра. как остановить функцию управления при проигрыше

Tags: javascript

нужно чтоб, при столкновений самолета с птицей самолет падал и управление отключался, попробовал вот так, все равно не отключается

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownmove);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupmove);

function keydownmove(e) {   
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        left = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        up = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        right = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        down = true;
    }
    if (game_over == true) {
        return false;
    }
}       

function keyupmove(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        left = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        up = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        right = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        down = false;
    }
}

if (up == true) {
    yPlane -= 4;
}
if (left == true) {
    xPlane -= 4;
}
if (right == true) {
    xPlane += 4;
}
if (down == true) {
    yPlane += 4;
}

if (game_over == true) {
    yPlane +=5;
}
```

Comment: Так себе у Вас самолет

Comment: Покажите фукнцию, в которой Вы пытаетесь отключить управление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы решить Вашу проблему, достаточно просто открепить обработчики нажатий:

```
//Допустим, у Вас есть объект plan, который отвечает за поведение самолета, тогда
plan.onCrash = function() {
  this.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownmove)
  this.removeEventListener("keyup", keyupmove)
}
```